# Sometimes select2 is not working/loaded in moodle plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, jquery-select2, moodle

I worked with [moodle](https://moodle.org/) and I created a plugin in it. In this one I used the library [select2](https://select2.org/).

In my view.php file of the plugin, I have:

```
    foreach((array) $jsFiles as $path) {
    $PAGE->requires->js(new moodle_url($CFG->wwwroot . '/mod/exam/subplugins/'.$path));
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Essential to activate bootstrap -->


<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="select2/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="select2/select2.full.js"></script>
<link href="select2/chart.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="select2/chart.min.js"></script>
<title></title>
</head>
<?php

?>
</html>

<?php
echo $OUTPUT->footer();
```

So, I load the library here.
And I use it in the javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var script =  $.getScript("../../mod/exam/select2/select2.min.js");
    init();
});
```

The first time, I loaded the script just in the ready function, but now I load it also in the init function and by doing this, it works more often.
And I also have a button to add a select2 field. And I loaded the script with the `$.getScript` function in the top of this function to make it works more often. If I don't do that when I click on the button, the most of the time, it doesn't work and I have something like that:

[image: select2 not loaded]

In my local machine on windows 10 it works 9 times on 10 with all browsers (chrome, firefox...)

I tested it on another machine on ubuntu, and it worked really not often with all browsers.
And I also tested it on a virtual machine on linux and it's like in localhost. When I access it from my machine on windows 10, it works 9 times on 10 and on the machine on ubuntu, it worked really rarely.

When it doesn't work, I have this error: `Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function(u){var e=function...` from require.min.js and after, this one: `createexam.js:98 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function` from my javascript file.

I also tried to load the library in other way provided by moodle like `$this->page->requires->js(...)` or without `$.getScript` function. But each time, it works less often than now.

So, do you have an idea why it doesn't work each time on all machines? Or do I load the library not in the good way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never worked with Moodle but I worked with RequireJS. Your site uses `RequireJS` and `select2` does support `RequireJS`. So you have to load it via `RequireJS`. Otherwise it will not work when `RequireJS` loads as first - so from time to time :)

Use RequireJS:

```
require(['select2/select2.full.js', 'select2/chart.min.js'], function () {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var script =  $.getScript("../../mod/exam/select2/select2.min.js", function () {
      init()
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently moodle js caching is the reason.
Administration->appearence->ajax and javascript->turn off caching.

UPD: so my select2 was working during page initial rendering, but once document was ready select2 never registered again with that 'select2 is not a function' message.
I checked several times if jquery loads twice, the order of my scripts etc.

```
$.noConflict(true)
```

Helped me finally. I put it before select2 calls, jquery resovles its inner issues and the error is gone.